# Android throwing ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have installed and used

```
compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
```

many times, but now it is throwing ClassNotFoundException.

Any idea what might be the reason.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.app.job.JobServiceEngine" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/app.###.###-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/app.###.###-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

Comment: What happened when you cleaned and rebuilt your project?

Comment: i tried to even invalidate cache, nothing worked, so i used another ORM (Realm) which works like a churm, Thanks anyway.